# how to display image on left and paragraph on right on the same line

Tags: html, inline-code

I want to do inline html styling, I want an image to float left and the paragraph on the right side by side on the same line, however I'm not getting the desired result with the code below:

My code is below or please view a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMv5u/)

index.html

```
<div class="newWrapper">
    <div class="person1" style="float:left; display:inline-block; ">
        <img src=simonwilliams.jpg width="auto" height"auto" clear:both;/>
        <p style="float:right; display:block;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer arcu mauris, ullamcorper et ligula vitae, hendrerit sodales tellus. Maecenas quis pulvinar lacus.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="person2" style="float:left" display:inline-block;>
        <img src=simonwilliams.jpg width="auto" height"auto"/>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer arcu mauris, ullamcorper et ligula vitae, hendrerit sodales tellus. Maecenas quis pulvinar lacus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a span and make it `float:left` and also add the span for the `<p>` tag and make it `float:right`. At the same time if you want to do for the below `div` you can do the same.

```
 <div class="person1" style="float:left; display:inline-block; ">
        <span style="float:left;width: 20%;">
            <img src="http://www.ninahale.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Google.jpg"  
             width="70" height"70" />
        </span>
        <span style="float:right;width: 80%;">
            <p style="float:right; display:block;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,    
                    consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer arcu mauris, ullamcorper et 
                    ligula vitae, hendrerit sodales tellus. Maecenas quis pulvinar 
                    lacus.
            </p>
        </span>
 </div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BMv5u/4/)

Answer (score 1):

What about a table and two TDs?

```
   <div>
    <table>
        <td><img src=simonwilliams.jpg width="auto" height"auto" clear:both;/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer arcu mauris, ullamcorper et ligula vitae, hendrerit sodales tellus. Maecenas quis pulvinar lacus.
        </td>
        <td>
<img src=simonwilliams.jpg width="auto" height"auto" clear:both;/>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer arcu mauris, ullamcorper et ligula vitae, hendrerit sodales
  tellus. Maecenas quis pulvinar lacus.
        </td>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: i can achieve this in a table but I wouldn't want this in a table